# Do wordpress website with other host shows ads?

Tags: wordpress, adsense

I am using Godaddy hosting and uses wordpress application to build my website. I want to apply for Google Adsense and want to monetize my site. Will ads appear on my website?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about 3rd party hosting, bot about programming

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, ads can be added on your site. You can either insert your ads code directly on your page content or simply get a [plugin](https://www.shoutmeloud.com/best-adsense-plugins-wordpress.html) that can help you integrate ads on your site.